# Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native component where I need to use `ComponentDidMount`. Also in `ComponentDidMount` i'm using `setState`because I am not sure of any other way to solve my purpose. I guess for this reason I am getting the error: `Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate`. Although i'm not using `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`. Here's the code I have:

```js
   currentUsers=()=>{
        let dbRef = firebase.database().ref('Users');
        dbRef.on('child_added', (val)=>{
            let person = val.val();
            person.phone = val.key;
            this.setState((prevState)=> {
                return {
                    users: [...prevState.users, person]
                }
            })
        })
    }

    componentWillMount(){
      this.currentUsers();
    }
```

What can I do to resolve the error?

Comment: This looks ok. Can you share full component snippet ?

Comment: This is the component: https://codeshare.io/5wWDdK   .Error throws when I try to navigate to this component: https://codeshare.io/G8jzyB @Easwar

Comment: Both these files have same content.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's the homescreen: https://codeshare.io/2W9pdd . Error shows onpressing to navigate to chatscreen.

Comment: Still not able to figure out why. Can you tell the exact line or method which is throwing the error ? Is the api call in `ChatScreen`'s componentDidMount executing ?

Comment: In homescreen there is a function renderRow and in the function there in an onpess event. The error is thrown when this onPress is fired.

Comment: How many users do you have? Since you're using the updater version of `setState` and `on('child_added')` gets fired for every existing item in the db (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) it seems likely you're hitting the error because you're simply calling `setState` too many times in a single render cycle. Can you fetch the initial user set in one call and only call setState once and the subscribe to future changes instead?

Comment: Can you show me what changes I need to made? @azundo

Comment: in the chatscreen can you replace onChangeText={this.handleChange('textMessage')}  to onChangeText={() =>this.handleChange('textMessage')}

Comment: The error comes before that. It occurs before showing the chatscreen. @GauravRoy

Comment: can you try once with what ive provided. and letme knwo if it works

Comment: Sorry still the same. @GauravRoy

Comment: Don't know why but it works... @GauravRoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so , the error was basically calling a func in the the render method which calls the setState again  , and hence an infinite loop. It's always advisable to use anonymous function while calling in the render method. So replacing

```
onChangeText={this.handleChange('textMessage')} to onChangeText={() =>this.handleChange('textMessage')}
```

Worked for you. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide code for the whole Class component?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/2W9pdd  is the homescreen and https://codeshare.io/G8jzyB is the chatscreen. Error throws while navigating to chatscreen. @DagurLeo